# How do I get a reference to MS Access in .Net Core 3.0?

Tags: c#, .net, ms-access, .net-core

I'm looking for some help.  I am in need of figuring out how to get an object reference to Microsoft Access 2013 so that I can (through Automation) call some of the already defined functions in the accdb.  For instance; I want to automate the process of "RelinkODBCTables" function which repoints the linked tables to another data source from my .net core 3.0 c# application.
I've not been able to successfully get a reference to interop but I may not be doing it correctly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

D-

Answer (score 1):

If you want to

Create a instnce of Access.

Call a VBA sub (say your relink code).

Close the the database.

quit access.

You could use this code:

```
{
object AccessApp;

AccessApp = Interaction.CreateObject("Access.Application");

AccessApp.OpenCurrentDatabase(@"c:\test\test44.accdb");

AccessApp.Run("MyLinker");

AccessApp.CloseCurrentDatabase();
AccessApp.Quit();

}
```

So, you don't need any referance at all. Just create a instance of the given applicatin (word, Excel or as per above Access).

At that point, you have full use of the object model, and can use run to call some VBA routine. In above, we call a VBA Sub called MyRelinker.

About the only caution here is that when you create the instance of that object, then all startup code of the application will run. So, if on startup the forms and UI that the developer of the Access program launches any prompt, then you can't "answer" that prompt. So, how well this works will VERY much depend on how nice the application plays on startup, and that calling any of those VBA routines does not trigger some kind of prompt(s) in that Access application. If it does, then you in trouble, since you can't "answer" any of the forms or code prompts that access may very well throw up at the end user.

And, if you do want some "inteli-sense" during coding, then you can add a office "interop" reference to your project. Its not required, but if you not really fluent in the Access VBA + object model, then in place of CreateObject("Access.Application"), if you do referance the office assemby, say this one:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\
Visual Studio Tools for Office\PIA\Office14\
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.dll
```

Then you code becomes this:

```
{
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Application AccessApp = 
  new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Application();

AccessApp.OpenCurrentDatabase(@"c:\test\test44.accdb");
AccessApp.Run("MyLinker");

AccessApp.CloseCurrentDatabase();

AccessApp.Quit();
}
```

However, while you get stronger typing with the reference, you often will "tie" you code to a given version of Access, and a simple use of CreateObject() quite much means that you can create a instance of Any Access installed on the target computer, and it should work going back all the way to office 2000 - a good 20 years of "coverage".

Keep in mind that you CAN NOT create a instance of the Access runtime, the target computer will requite a full version to "create" a instance of the Access.Application object.

You "can" automate the runtime version. This involves launching Access runtime (via Shell()), and then grabbing an instance with "GetObject()" in place of CreateObject().

## Edit

I should point out that in the 2nd above code example, and using the office interop-assembly reference, I choose office 14, which is office 2010. In your case, you have to use office 15 (2013).